# How to build a Min-Max Heap in O(n) time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, minmax-heap

I found the topic of [min-max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap) on Wikipedia. I was wondering if there is any way of building this min-max heap in `O(n)`.

I know you can do this with both min heap and max heap, but I'm not sure what would be the approach for this. Inserting an element takes `O(log n)` time complexity and I feel like this kind of tree can't be build more efficiently than `O(n log n)`.

Comment: That wikipedia article indicates that you can use Floyd's O(n) algorithm to build a min-max heap. There are also references which help explain why that algorithm is O(n).

Comment: I really tried to understand that alogirthm, but as I just started studying algorithms it's quite hard for me to understand, that's why I was hoping to get some help here.

Comment: The best way to understand simple algorithms is with pencil and paper. Try it out on some inputs and you will probably see how it works. (It's the same approach which is used to build the heap in the heapsort algorithm, which might be easier to work through.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can. In your *build-heap* loop, you simply call `TrickleDown`, just like you would with a min heap or a max heap. That function will move the item accordingly, depending on whether it's on a min level or a max level.

See the original paper, [Min-Max Heaps and Generalized Priority Queues](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.84.3173&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for general info. The paper doesn't implement *build-heap*, but if you write your own that calls `TrickleDown`, it works as expected. That is:

```
for i = A.length/2 downto 0
    TrickleDown(i)
```

`TrickleDown` determines if `i` is on a min level or a max level, and calls the appropriate method, `TrickleDownMin` or `TrickleDownMax`.

Comment: what is the time complexity of TrickleDown(i) to determine where i move.

Comment: @DHARMENDRASINGH `TrickleDown(i)` has worst-case time complexity of O(log n). But in the context of the build-heap operation, we know how the maximum number of calls to `TrickleDown` will be made, and what the complexity will be. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/49774237/56778